# Installing yearofmoo demo on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to go through the demos at http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-testacular.html#testacular and seem to be having a problem installing the demos on W7 64-bit. I have Node and Git installed and have the required repositories cloned locally, but starting the server is the problem. The server.sh file contains the instruction:

```
nf --procfile ./config/Procfile.server start
```

If I try to run that in Node it complains about not having an ENV file. Any suggestions or specific instructions would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you provide a direct link to the code that's involved?

Comment: The link in the question has everything that is being referenced. If you go through the setup steps on a W7 machine you should come upon the same problem. One of my co-workers mentioned something about a program for W7 that emulates all of the Linux commands, so I might be heading down that route.